# UIImage & CGPoint & CGSize could not be found in the scope XCode

Tags: swift, xcode

Странные ошибки получил сегодня в своем проекте, все работало и вдруг (я думаю), что то поменялось в настройках проекта и теперь в (одельном) файле extentions я получаю ошибки

```
extension UIImage {
    
    func draw(logo: UIImage, position: CGPoint, logoSize: CGSize? = nil) -> UIImage {
        let fixedImage = fixImageOrientation()
...
```

вот так выглядят ошибки

[image]

выглядит как будто, что то изменилось в настройках проекта, потому что это работало и вдруг перестало.

P.S. если я добавляю `import UIKit` то это решает проблему, но все равно интересно, как так получается, что все работало и теперь мне нужно добавлять доплнительные импорты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно у Вас есть Bridging Header и в нём было прописано:

```
@import UIKit;
или
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

В таком случае в Swift файлах не нужен

```
import UIKit
```

После удаления, соответственно, начал требовать. Может из-за фреймворка с `UIKit` зависимостью, а после его удаления/обновления начал требовать.
Может ещё что-то, нужно смотреть что менялось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, скорее всего это то, что произошло, спасибо